# How to draw in three-dimensional coordinate system in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

I want to create a drawing using a three-dimensional coordinate system in Inkskape. I am trying to re-create a drawing similar to the image below:

[image]

Right now, I am make three arrows and attach them manually to each other. I am wondering whether there is a more standard way of doing that in Inkscape, i.e., creating a frame in Inkscape with all three axis connected at the centre to form one entity.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking.  Are you asking us to help you *make a 3D co-ordinate system* in InkScape, or simply draw the image that you've posted?

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. I needed to recreate the image I posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I would do. This may already be what you are doing but to my knowledge there is no quicker way to do this:

1. Draw a line pointing to the right (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).
2. Draw a line pointing upwards (hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).
3. Draw a line pointing to the bottom right (or whereever you want).
4. Enable *snapping* and *snap to cusp nodes.*
5. Move the lines together until they snap.
6. Select all lines and add arrow heads (in the *stroke style* dialogue).
7. If desired, group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) or combine (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know how to join the three axis (lines) at one point without adding to errors because of manual attempt. _Snapping_ and _snap to cusp nodes_ is what I was missing.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear from your question whether you are just trying to recreate the image in your question, draw a 3D grid, or draw something with a 3D grid for reference. [Wrzlprmft's answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/80851/16458) already covers drawing something like your image, so I'll cover the other two.

## Draw on a 3D grid

Inkscape has a grid that you can used to guide your drawing, such as snapping points to it. To show the grid, on the **View** menu click **Page Grid** or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

The default grid is 2D. To use a 3D grid, do the following.

1. On the **File** menu, click **Document Properties**.
2. In the Document Properties on the **Grids** tab, in the **Creation** box, select *Axonometric grid*, and then click **New**.
   If there is an existing grid in the **Defined Grids**, you may want to deselect **Enabled** or just remove that grid.
3. If not already visible, on the **View** menu, click **Page Grid**.

You can use the snapping tools so that when you draw or move, it'll snap to this grid. If you don't see the snapping tools, on the **View** menu, hover over **Show/Hide** and click **Snap Controls Bar**.

## Draw a 3D grid

If your goal is to draw an object that looks like a 3D grid, use the render isometric grid extension. This is found in *Extensions > Render > Grids > Isometric Grid*. Experiment with the various options to get the grid you want (or close enough), and then manually edit it by hand if needed. The rendered grid will be a drawn object that you can manipulate and edit.

This would be an alternative to draw something similar to your posted image. Render a grid with a size of 1 in all directions and change subdivisions to 0. Ungroup it and delete paths you don't need, and then make the remaining stuff look however you want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's good to learn these Grid features.